# How to use Material UI Tooltip with TableRow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, material-ui

I am trying to wrap a MUI TableRow inside a Tooltip component so hovering over the row shows a long uuid, but when I do this the columns of the row are all compressed into the first column, the layout is not preserved. How do I resolve this? I have tried wrapping the entire row and also just wrapping 'defaultRender' but the result is the same, all columns get squished and displayed in the first column.

Below is the table component code.

```
    <Table
      isLoading={loadingFetchBatches}
      total={meta.total}
      limit={meta.limit}
      currentPage={meta.currentPage}
      order={meta.order}
      sort={meta.sort}
      columns={columns}
      rows={batches}
      sortableFields={meta.sortableFields}
      onClickSortRow={handleSortRow}
      onChangePage={handleChangePage}
      onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
      overrideTr={({ defaultRender }) => {
        const batch = defaultRender?.[0]?.props?.row;
        return (
          <Tooltip title={batch.batchId}>
            <TableRow
              onClick={() => {
                setCurrentBatch({ ...batch });
                  history.push(`/connect/summary/messages`);
                }}
                selected={isCurrentBatch(batch?.batchId)}
                cursor="pointer"
                hover
            >
              {defaultRender}
            </TableRow>
          </Tooltip> 
        );
      }}
    />
```

help always appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 0):

you do not have table cells in your code (at least we cannot see it) but try to wrap the tablecell with tooltip, or the row.. it works both like this:

```
<TableBody>
  {rows.map((row) => (
          <Tooltip title="Tooltip 1">
            <TableRow
              key={row.name}
              sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 } }}
            >
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.name}
              </TableCell>
              <Tooltip title="Tooltip 2"><TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell></Tooltip>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </Tooltip>
  ))}
</TableBody>
```

Comment: The cells are passed into the table in the 'columns' attribute. 'columns' is an array of column data, here is an example of a cell, which i have also tried to wrap individually, but returns no data whatsoever when wrapped inside the tooltip:
 {
      field: "sent",
      headerName: t("sent_count"),
      width: "10%",
      renderCell: ({ row }) => {
        return <Tooltip title="I am a tooltip!">{row?.sentCount}</Tooltip>;
      },
    },

Comment: is not defaultRender an array and you need to map it to table cells?

Comment: defaultRender is an object which inside somewhere contains the row, if i do not wrap it in the tooltip, defaultRender  simply displays the row with the columns defined in the previously provided array, so it displays as a table should. its just the tooltip that compresses all the fields into one column